# NCurses segfault on wgetnstr unless enter pressed first

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I'm getting a strange crash (SIGSEGV) in an application I'm writing using NCurses on text input. The segfault happens consistently any time I try to enter text -unless- I send an enter first, at which point everything works as intended. At a bit of a loss here, and hoping somebody might have an idea of how to fix it or at least what's wrong.

Currently using ncurses 5.9. (from Debian Wheezy apt repo, corresponds to commit 983732ea2cf3ed288555ddfa4090ca7825901c40 in the Debian source repository at http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/ncurses.git/tree/?h=wheezy&id=983732ea2cf3ed288555ddfa4090ca7825901c40)

I can, as needed, post other parts of my code (including the whole Console class and the main function).

Code:

```
void Console::readinput() {
  char* input;
  if (!(input = (char*)calloc(1, 1024))) {
    exit(212);
  }

  int r = wgetnstr(winp, input, 1024);
  updatewinp();

  if (r == ERR) readout();
  else if (r == KEY_RESIZE) redrawall();
  else if (input == 0) return;
  else if (strlen(input) == 0) redrawall();
  else if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) running = false;
  else sendmsg(input);

  free(input);
}
```

Backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff79a61cc in waddch_literal (ch=<optimized out>, win=0x7bb080) at /build/buildd-ncurses_5.9-10-amd64-5ex5DJ/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/base/lib_addch.c:384
#1  waddch_nosync (ch=<optimized out>, win=0x7bb080) at /build/buildd-ncurses_5.9-10-amd64-5ex5DJ/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/base/lib_addch.c:434
#2  waddch (win=win@entry=0x7bb080, ch=<optimized out>) at /build/buildd-ncurses_5.9-10-amd64-5ex5DJ/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/base/lib_addch.c:539
#3  0x00007ffff79ab261 in wgetnstr (win=0x7bb080, str=0x864cc1 "", maxlen=1024) at /build/buildd-ncurses_5.9-10-amd64-5ex5DJ/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/base/lib_getstr.c:151
#4  0x000000000049f8b8 in Console::readinput() () at /home/admin/entropy/src/server/Console/Console.cpp:147
#5  0x00000000004ebd22 in main () at /home/admin/entropy/src/server/Entropy/main.cpp:55
```

Thank you ahead of time for any help.

Comment: Haven't solved the issue, but I have managed to work around it. Prompting for the user to hit any key in a blocking call, then having a getch() with noecho() up seems to force a fix of... whatever was happening there. Still interested if anybody has any ideas, but there's a workaround otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the issue was 100% unrelated. I used delwin on the window whenever I had to redraw it. However, this redraw was usually triggered by another thread printing something to it. Using wclear instead of delwin/newwin fixes everything, as does not actually redrawing winp when I don't need to. Admittedly, having done so in the first place was probably stupid of me anyway.